# Aligning an Image for OCR

Tags: matlab, image-processing, alignment

I am trying to align an image as a preprocessing step for OCR.
The problem is that I wish to align regions in images that contain text without using a template of an aligned image.

My idea was to first extract the borders of the ROI:

[image]

Then, draw some rectangle with fitting proportions(haven't thought on a way to do it automaticlly yet), and try to estimate the geometric transformation between them by using [imregcorr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregcorr.html):

[image]

After that, apply the obtained transformation on the image itself:

[image]

As you can see, the final result is far from perfect.

So I wish to know if there is a better way to obtain the coordinates change between the border and the rectangle and apply it on the image.

There's also the possiblity that my approach is too naive, and the solution to this is completely different, so feel free to suggest other methods as you see fit.

Thanks.

Comment: with no additional prior knowledge, how do you expect to recover the original text width?

Comment: How accurately can you detect the rectangular frame around the text?

Comment: Not very accurately, the current frame is drawn manually, as my initial goal is to align the image.

Using hough, I only manged to obtain part of the border.

Comment: If this is always your test case, so you can find the rectangle (contoured by red color in the first image), then easily you will find its four corners, those are the source points, then you may define your reference points, here you have all what you need to calculate the homography matrix. I suggest you using Opencv

Comment: For Opencv choice check this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks dervish!

I don't really know much about openCV, as I still have to learn C++/python (soon I will, probably).
But I did manage to implement something similar in matlab, using a projective transformation:

```
m = [mx my]; % Red border corners
s=[sx sy]; % Fixed rectangle borders
BW = poly2mask(mx,my,168,290); 
mask = uint8(repmat(BW,[1 1 3]));
TFORM = cp2tform(m,s, 'projective');
Iw = imtransform(I.*mask,TFORM);
[y,x] = find(im2bw(Iw,0));
imshow(Iw(min(y):max(y),min(x):max(x),:))
```

And here's the result:

[image]